# Can you push a _trackEvent with value but no label?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

If entering a label when a value is specified is redundant do you have to specify the label?  Do you just enter a blank string, null value or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [Google Docs for _trackEvent()](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiEventTracking#_gat.GA_EventTracker_._trackEvent) recommend using `undefined` for optional parameters as needed.